# How can I Dynamically change gradientstop color for RadialGradientBrush in Uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I Dynamically change gradientstop color for RadialGradientBrush in Uwp?

Example declaration:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="xBackground" Canvas.Left="12.25" Canvas.Top="12.25" Width="75" Height="75" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="Black" >
<Ellipse.Fill>
    <media:RadialGradientBrush >
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding OnColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorLightConverter}, ConverterParameter=50, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF2CA5DF"/>
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding OnColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Offset="0.5"/>
    </media:RadialGradientBrush>
</Ellipse.Fill>
```

Comment: In your scenario, you have used `TemplatedParent` as the source of `GradientStop`, so the color can’t change. I suggest you could create a public property named `MyColor` in code-behind and use **Color="{Binding MyColor, Mode=OneWay** to bind in XAML page, you will achieve the effect that you wanted when you change the MyClor property in code-behind.

Comment: for example for example

Comment: not working not working

Comment: What type the OnColor is? Is it System.Windows.Media.Color?

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty OnColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "OnColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ToggleButtonBasic), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Green));

Comment: UWP not wpf  UWP not wpf

Comment: Could you please provide us a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by OneDrive or GitHub?